# Show 2d Array row and column counter

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I want to show array row and column counter. Hope you understand my Question.
Images at the bottom.

```
        char[,] arr = new char[4, 4]
        {
            { '☺', '♣', '♦', '♠'},
            { '♥', '♫', '☼', '☺'},
            { '☺', '♣', '♦', '♠'},
            { '♥', '♫', '☼', '☺'},
        };
        int rowLength = arr.GetLength(0);
        int colLength = arr.GetLength(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("\t{0} ", arr[i, j]));
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output: [Image without counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA4lC.png)

Instead of: [Image with counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9jZc.png)

Comment: So what you are trying to do is to display the contents of the array in a table format with column numbers across the top and row numbers along the side?

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guess that you need to see rows and columns numbers.
You need to add them in code in order to see them.
Something like this:

```
char[,] arr = new char[4, 4]
    {
        { '☺', '♣', '♦', '♠'},
        { '♥', '♫', '☼', '☺'},
        { '☺', '♣', '♦', '♠'},
        { '♥', '♫', '☼', '☺'},
    };
        int rowLength = arr.GetLength(0);
        int colLength = arr.GetLength(1);
        Console.Write("\t");
        for (int row =1; row<5; row++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("\t{0}", row));
        }
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("\t{0} ", i+1));
            for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("\t{0} ", arr[i, j]));
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Beautiful @Rumenand, it works.
Thank you for saving my time.